# Add Inline images to Lotus notes mail

Tags: lotus-notes

I have an application which reads the eml and convert it to NSF mails using C API. I am able to add HTML Body to it using NSFMimePartAppendStream method but my problem is how to add inline images to it.
By using method MailAddMessageAttachment attachment are getting added as normal attachment but how should map the Content id to it. Can any one please explain how to add inline images to mail body?

Regards,
HAseena

Comment: Issue is solved using MIME Content, reading the mime entirely with attachmenst and inline images "MIMEStreamWrite"

Comment: Then please close off the question.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is solved using MIME Content, reading the mime entirely with attachmenst and inline images "MIMEStreamWrite"